# Does __attribute__((const)) work on Objective-C method with Clang?

Tags: objective-c, attributes, clang

`__attribute__((const))` is a GCC attribution to check purity of the function execution.
I think this is being supported on Clang, but when I put this to a method, it doesn't seem to work.

```
@interface C1
- (id)method1 __attribute__((const));
@end


int a = 0;

@implementation C1
- (id)method1 __attribute__((const))
{
    a++;
    return nil;
}
@end
```

The code above doesn't generate any warning or error.

Is this attribution working on Clang? Or what should I do to make this to work?

Comment: I'm trying to clean up the [tag:pure] tag, which sometimes refers to [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/), or [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_(programming_language)) or "pure CSS". I don't know Objective C, so if my edit makes no sense, please let me know.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I updated the tag to `purity` which makes sense. Objective-C doesn't support pure virtual functions as language construct, but the behavior can be simulated with dynamic check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `const` attribute doesn't *check* the purity of the function.  It *declares* the purity of the function, so the optimizer can eliminate calls to the function.  It's up to you to actually make sure the function is pure.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a method `const` can not work in Objective-C because it contradicts the runtime's message passing mechanism. [The documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for `const` says:

> Note that a function that has pointer arguments and examines the data pointed to must not be declared const.

Every Objective-C method has at least one (implicit) pointer argument: `self`. It is *always* examined as part of message passing (`objc_msgSend()`). That's what makes Objective-C dynamic.

Comment: I am sure that `__attribute__((const))` and `const` keyword are different stuffs.

Comment: @Eonil I should make clear that I'm talking about the gcc extension to decorate functions: `__attribute__((const))`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Now I am confusing because it simply didn't make any warning or error when I asking this question. Now I assume that Clang is just silently ignoring the attribute for Objective-C methods.

Comment: @Eonil That's probably the right thing to do. Attributes are used to implement compiler extensions. One compiler should probably not complain over another's attributes, so there's no warning. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Message passing (`objc_msgSend()`) happens *before* the method itself (C-function you write in `@implementation`) is run, so I believe it's perfectly reasonable to declare *the method itself* to be `__attribute__((const))`. For this to be an honest declaration, the method must ignore `self`. As you correctly say, Objective-C compiler probably will not be able to **use** this information.

Comment: @ilyan. The `const` attribute is used on the *declaration* of a function. This gives a hint about its intended use in a compiler: optimizing the call, not the implementation. When translating a function the compiler sees the implementation, so it can adjust its optimization strategies to the memory accesses the function makes. On the other hand when calling a function it usually only sees the declaration. When the compiler knows (from the declaration) that a function has no side effects it can perform various call site optimizations, like common subexpression elimination.